# Mfc feature pack CMFCOutlookBar not showing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, visual-c++-2010, mfc-feature-pack

I'm developing a SDI project with MFC 2010 using the 'new' MFC feature pack to add some stuffs.

The template added me the Calendar bar and Tree bar, pretty unuseful to my application. I removed some of them and replaced one with a CDialogEx derived class and everything works fine.

Now, I want to definitely remove all of old template panel and use mines, but as soon as I remove the code commenting it, the whole control will not show anymore.

Worst part, if I decomment the control still not show. Sometimes, removing the registry key associated will let the control show for just one run.

I'll paste code:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////> .H File
class CMainFrame : public CFrameWndEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMainFrame)
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    protected:
         CCalendarBar           m_wndCalendar; //> Old pane
CEliCUTP140PannelloDlg* m_pPannelloDlg;        //> Derived from CDialogEx
CMFCMenuBar             m_wndMenuBar;
CMFCOutlookBar          m_wndBarraPannelli;    //> Outlook bar
CMFCOutlookBarPane*     m_pCurrOutlookPage;    //> Dunno what's for
CMFCOutlookBarTabCtrl*  m_pCurrOutlookWnd;     //> Same as above
CMFCShellTreeCtrl       m_wndTree;             //> Old pane
CMFCStatusBar           m_wndStatusBar;
CMFCToolBar             m_wndToolBar;
CMFCToolBarImages       m_UserImages;
//////////////////////////////////////////> .CPP file.
m_wndBarraPannelli.SetMode2003();
if (strTemp.LoadString(theApp.m_hRisorse, IDS_SHORTCUTS) == FALSE)
{
    m_Log.AddString(_T("CMainFrame::CreateOutlookBar - Impossibile caricare la stringa IDS_SHORTCUTS."));
    throw CGUIException(E_GE_IMP_CAR_STR);
}
dwOpzioni = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_LEFT;
if (m_wndBarraPannelli.Create(strTemp, this, CRect(0, 0, nInitialWidth, 32000), uiID, dwOpzioni, AFX_CBRS_OUTLOOK_TABS) == FALSE)
    return FALSE;
dwStyle = AFX_CBRS_FLOAT | AFX_CBRS_AUTOHIDE | AFX_CBRS_RESIZE;
dwOpzioni = CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
m_wndBarraPannelli.SetPaneStyle(m_wndBarraPannelli.GetPaneStyle() | dwOpzioni);
m_wndBarraPannelli.SetButtonsFont(&afxGlobalData.fontBold);

pOutlookBar = (CMFCOutlookBarTabCtrl *)m_wndBarraPannelli.GetUnderlyingWindow();
if (pOutlookBar == NULL)
    return FALSE;
pOutlookBar->EnableInPlaceEdit(FALSE);
pOutlookBar->EnableAnimation(TRUE);
pOutlookBar->EnableScrollButtons();
pOutlookBar->SetBorderSize(1);
pOutlookBar->SetPageButtonTextAlign(TA_LEFT);

    /* the last panel which I'm trying to remove
    const DWORD             dwTreeStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT | TVS_HASBUTTONS;

    tree.Create(dwTreeStyle, rectDummy, pOutlookBar, 1200);
    if (strTemp.LoadString(theApp.m_hRisorse, IDS_FOLDERS) == FALSE)
    {
        m_Log.AddString(_T("CMainFrame::CreateOutlookBar - Impossibile caricare la stringa IDS_FOLDERS."));
        throw CGUIException(E_GE_IMP_CAR_STR);
    }
    pOutlookBar->AddControl(&tree, strTemp, 2, TRUE, dwStyle);**/

if (m_pPannelloDlg == NULL)
    m_pPannelloDlg = new CEliCUTP140PannelloDlg();
m_pPannelloDlg->m_pSuperParent = this;
bNameValid = m_pPannelloDlg->Create(IDD_ELICUTP140PANNELLODLG, &m_wndBarraPannelli);
m_pPannelloDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
if (strTemp.LoadString(theApp.m_hRisorse, IDS_PAN_MOV) == FALSE)
{
    m_Log.AddString(_T("CMainFrame::CreateOutlookBar - Impossibile caricare la stringa IDS_PAN_MOV."));
    throw CGUIException(E_GE_IMP_CAR_STR);
}
pOutlookBar->AddControl(m_pPannelloDlg, strTemp, 0, TRUE, dwStyle);
m_wndBarraPannelli.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

pOutlookBar->SetImageList(theApp.m_bHiColorIcons ? IDB_PAGES_HC : IDB_PAGES, 24);
pOutlookBar->SetToolbarImageList(theApp.m_bHiColorIcons ? IDB_PAGES_SMALL_HC : IDB_PAGES_SMALL, 16);
pOutlookBar->RecalcLayout();
bAnimation = theApp.GetInt(_T("OutlookAnimation"), TRUE);
CMFCOutlookBarTabCtrl::EnableAnimation(bAnimation);
```

If I should paste extra code let me know.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you post the Header file(.h) code also? need to know the class types of these variables. m_wndBarraPannelli, tree, and m_pPannelloDlg specifically

Comment: Code updated. I've read somewhere that CDialogEx can't be used as panel, but Documentation says that I can use any CWnd. Honestly I'm confused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those interested in this problem:

[SOCIAL MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcf45201-1bf2-438f-906a-325d1a1d3d34/mfc-feature-pack-cmfcoutlookbar-not-showing?forum=vcgeneral#bcf45201-1bf2-438f-906a-325d1a1d3d34)

It's the link to Microsoft's forum with the answer. Moderators can close this topic.